# Kali Linux end Kernel Panic exitcode=0x0000000b

Tags: linux, kernel, kali

when I start my Raspberry Pi 4 with 4GB Ram comes the following:
`{1.174936} ---{ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000000 }---`

Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: kali is a distribution for Linux experts.

Comment: Welcome -- please read the section [here](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/) titled *Is Kali Linux Right For You?*  This issue is not unique to the Pi and [there are plenty of discussions of it online already](https://www.google.com/search?q=end+Kernel+panic+-+not+syncing).  If there is any point to you using Kali, you should be able to glean enough from that.  If it is too confusing, then your solution should be giving up on Kali.